# Is there any way to subclass a C# interface in a way that *restricts* behavior?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, abstract-class

```
public interface IBlackBox<T> {
  bool IsValid();
  T GetValue();
}

public abstract class Box<T>:IBlackBox<T> {
  public bool IsValid() {
    return true;
  }
  public abstract T GetValue();
}
```

A `Box` produces a value on demand; could be an on-demand computation, or random, or just a fancy nullable, etc. A `BlackBox` does the same thing, except that it might expire or otherwise become invalid. `Box`es need to fit in `BlackBox` lists (and emphatically not the inverse), which dictates the inheritance hierarchy.

What I don't like is `Box` being an abstract class instead of an interface. This causes two headaches. First, it means I can't derive a `struct`, which would be very much preferred in the case of a `Box` which contains only a static value.

Second, it means I can't subclass anything else. For instance, one intended use is a `Dictionary<string,BlackBox<int>>` which is itself a `Box` and sums its values on demand. There's no good reason this shouldn't just subclass `Dictionary`, and at least one very good reason it should: not wrapping the `IDictionary` interface line-for-line! But there are places where I need the `Box` guarantee of validity, and it seems like I can only have one or the other.

I *could* have an `interface IBox<T> : IBlackBox<T>` which is empty and serves only as a "trust me" label. That would mean duplicating `Box`'s one-line `IsValid()` in every class that implements `IBox<T>`, but that's considerably less hassle than hand-wrapping `IDictionary`. I'm hoping for a more concrete solution, though.

Comment: So, tl;dr: you don't want to have to reimplement `IsValid` in every class implementing `IBlackBox` ? Note: it would be nice to split your question in two parts: the question, and the detais; I just woke up and had a hard time seeing where you were coming :p

Comment: To clarify: It's essential to have a discrete Box type where the result is guaranteed. A Box *must* be a BlackBox, and a BlackBox *must not* be a Box. What I really want is for Box to be an IBox interface, so I have the option of inheriting other classes or makgin structs.

Comment: "It's essential to have a discrete Box type where the result is guaranteed" - a) please put clarifications in the question itself, not in the comments, and b) please explain this requirement more precisely. _Why_ is that essential? Please show some code where you take advantage of the fact that for a `Box<T>`, you are guaranteed that the `IsValid()` method always returns `true`.

Comment: I keep re-reading this question and coming back to it feeling like despite what you've said, the inheritance is the wrong way around. Perhaps if you flip it and then have a separate interface that just serves as a marker for boxes that are definitely filled. If you need definitely filled boxes, you ask for the marker interface - otherwise, you have a set of `IBox`s and you determine that they have a value by their *either* actually having the marker interface *or* their being castable to `IBlackBox` and then you can use the `IsValid` method. Would that work for you?

Comment: I'm afraid that with your idea of implementing the interface in a struct you would get a small benefit (if any at all) and possibly run into some other problems: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2005/10/05/477238.aspx

Comment: @PeterDuniho It's essential because neither lines of code nor runtime cycles should be spent checking a condition that's guaranteed at compile time. You don't use nullables for a value that will never be null! It's essential *to the context of this question,* if you prefer exactness.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That's an interesting idea, but I think it causes as many problems as it solves. When working with combined sets, I'd need to do experimental casting first instead of being able to call `IsValid` indiscriminately... once again, it's code and cycles spent on something that should be entirely static.

Comment: "neither lines of code nor runtime cycles should be spent checking a condition that's guaranteed at compile time" -- since neither the lines of code nor the runtime cycles are going to in any way be a noticeable overhead or detriment, I find that rationale to be very weak. In any case, that explanation does nothing to provide the necessary elaboration/explanation of the question. The fact is, C# does not provide an actual mechanism to _restrict_ via inheritance, so you need to provide a more concrete example of what you are really trying to do if you want an actual answer here.

Comment: @PeterDuniho No offense, but your priorities aren't mine. What I posted satisfies my requirements, it just has a trade-offs I'd like to avoid if possible. Can I get the behavior I already have in a way that doesn't prevent inheriting other classes? If not, that IS an actual answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the best solution I've come up with. This is just the bare bones, but I've put a full implementation (with better names) [on GitHub](https://github.com/tejon/LiftedValues).

```
public interface IBlackBox
public interface IBlackBox<T> : IBlackBox {
  Func<T> GetValue;
}

public interface IBox { }
public interface IBox<T> : IBlackBox<T>, IBox { }

public interface IWrappedBox { }
public interface IWrappedBox<T> : IBox<IBlackBox<T>>, IWrappedBox { }

public interface IEmptyBox { }
public static class EmptyBox {
  public static EmptyBox<T> Get<T>() {
    return EmptyBox<T>.value;
  }
  sealed class EmptyBox<T> : IBlackBox<T>, IEmptyBox {
    public static readonly EmptyBox<T> value = new EmptyBox<T>();
    public Func<T> GetValue {
      get {
        throw new NotSupportedException
          ("Cannot extract a value from an empty box.");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The non-generic interfaces allow testing at the type level, for instance:

```
IBlackBox something = someWrappedBox.GetValue();
if (something is IEmptyBox)
  HandleEmpty();
else
  HandleSomething(something.GetValue());
```

This still has to be combined with three rules that the compiler can't check, but the structure makes it easy to conform:

- `IBlackBox<T>`, `IBlackBox` and `IEmptyBox` cannot be inherited directly.
- Only `IWrappedBox<T>.GetValue()` can return base `IBlackBox<T>`.
- Return values cannot specifically be any `IEmptyBox`.

`IEmptyBox` is guaranteed to show up only when explicitly permitted; `IBox<T>` is guaranteed to contain a good `T`;  and everything that can be inherited is an interface. Mission accomplished!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having an `IValidBox<T> : IBlackBox<T>` which a contract which specifies that no *legitimate* implementation may ever have `IsValid` return false, and that *consumers are entitled to call `GetValue` without checking `IsValid`*.  Additionally, to reduce boilerplate, you could define an abstract class `ValidBoxBase<T>` which implements `IValidBox<T>`, so that implementations of `IValidBox<T>` that don't need to inherit anything else could save some boilerplate.  Not much in this brief example, but perhaps a significant amount in more fleshed-out scenarios.